# retrieve raw IR image from Kinect

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there anyway to retrieve the raw IR image using the openni_kinect stack? Any other stack?

I'm pretty sure the old kinect calibration that was part of a different stack and that used a different driver published the raw IR image but it seems like the old calibration tutorial was taken down.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9525/retrieve-raw-ir-image-from-kinect/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now, we dont publish the IR images, but this feature is on our ToDo list, espectially with the calibration routines.

Suat

---

Originally posted by [Suat Gedikli](https://answers.ros.org/users/275/suat-gedikli/) with karma: 91 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1